# How can I block access to a directory on my PHP site?

Tags: php

I've a directory where I read/write data.

If any evil people discover a path to this directory on my website (i.e. `www.mysite.com/secretDir`), can they use it for storing their data?

If so, how can I stop it?

Comment: Not an ambitious or overly broad question at all. Fix the title please; admitting that it's not good enough is.. not good enough.

Comment: @Neal: Horrid spelling ;) @Sourav: Also, please stop writing tags in titles. SO already has tags.

Comment: @Tomalak, yea sorry about that. I think i typed too quickly

Comment: If it's in somewhere inside the document root of a website, then it can be accessed remotely. You can deny access based on a login or a cookie or referer or whatever, but nothing is 100% foolproof all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an FTP program like Filezilla or know how to change permissions through the command line, I would suggest you set your folders to `755` and most files to `644`. This is usually the default and keeps your files relatively protected. Other than that you could always password protect your directory if you want to block all traffic to the directory. Here is a nice tutorial on how to do that: http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the permissions are set correctly so outsiders do not have write access.

Comment: are you talking about chmod ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several layers to help prevent it. CHMOD the directory & any php scripts can prevent this. Also you can exclude apache/iis from serving the folder to the internet or ip ranges.

Broad answer to a broad question.